# PHP SOAPClient WSDL caching - couldn't load WSDL

Tags: php, caching, wsdl, soap-client

I am working with a very erratic SOAP API right now (using PHP's SOAPClient), which sometimes works fine and returns correct response, but most of the time it returns various errors.

One of these errors is "SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from ..."

I have WSDL caching enabled (`WSDL_CACHE_DISK`), and when WSDL is returned ok, a relevant file is created in the temp directory.

Now, I am calling the same endpoint multiple times during one processing, and even if the first call works fine (which means the WSDL is cached on the disk), the subsequent calls still return the "Couldn't load WSL" error.

I wonder why? If the WSDL is cached during the first call, shouldn't subsequent calls use it instead of trying to load it from remote server again?